# Font smoothing in Freya

Tags: fonts

I am currently trying make my terminal look more like the OSX terminal. Having installed the Menlo and Monaco fonts according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384551/mac-os-x-terminal-clone-for-ubuntu) description, I look in the dialog where the fonts are chosen and see that all monospace fonts look the same.

> Is this a bug?

Also:

> Is there some way to turn on font-smoothing of the terminal font? Is font-smoothing supported in Freya?

Comment: Which dialog? Are you using Pantheon Terminal or Gnome Terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Different fonts should look different, but the differences might be subtle. That being said, I switched my terminal to *Monaco* and the difference is noticable. Font-smoothing is available and enabled by default in Freya, including for the Terminal font, also for *Monaco*.

As far as I know Pantheon Terminal does not have a dialog to change its font. (There are other ways to do that though.)

Comment: Yeah, I use Pantheon and I set the font with Tweaks. I tried the gnome terminal, but it still looks different from my OS X terminal, which is kind of confusing.